# Select/Highlight option based on a div content

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

Below code suppose to match the dropdown list with the div content. If "Pineapple" is found, then select this option. I couldn't seem to find the error.

```
<head>
<script>
function displayResult(){

  var myObject=document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var myValue = $('#myContent').text();

  for(var i=0; i<myObject.length; i++){                        
      if(myObject.options[i].text == myValue){
          myObject.options[i].selected = true; 
          (also tried - myObject.options[i].selectedIndex = i;)
          break;
      }
  }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="myContent">Pineapple</div>

<form>
   Select your favorite fruit:
   <select id="mySelect" size="4">
     <option>Apple</option>
     <option>Orange</option>
     <option>Pineapple</option>
     <option>Banana</option>
   </select>
</form>

<button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Highlight Pineapple Option</button>

</body>
```

**Note:**

I want the option to be highlighted. Missing the closing bracket was a typo, corrected. Tried .selectedIndex=i, didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Because not only using jQuery?

Comment: jQuery one liner `$("#mySelect").val($('#myContent').text());`

Comment: Fixing the typo works just fine http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/4FWAA/

Comment: Do you mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/NUQcz/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `}` at the end of the function.

And you should either include jQuery library or change

```
var myValue = $('#myContent').text();
```

to

```
var myValue = document.getElementById('myContent').innerHTML;
```

---

A simpler trick to use, though, is (*not a good trick afterall...see @RobG's comment*)

```
function displayResult() {

    var myObject = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var myValue = document.getElementById('myContent').innerHTML;

    myObject.value = myValue;
}
```

but for IE the options will need to include the `value` attribute

```
<option value="Pineapple">Pineapple</option>
```

Comment: question for "myObject.value = myValue;": .value is the value sent to the server, not the text content between the div tags, correct? So it would be "P" if it is written as <option value = "P">Pineapple</option>.

Comment: The "simpler trick" does not work in IE 8 or less even with a value attribute. And better to use `textContent || innerText` than innerHTML to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
> myObject.options[i].selected = true;
```

use

```
myObject.selectedIndex = i;
```

Setting the selected property to true doesn't necessarily make the option selected (it varies between browsers).

Oh, and you have a syntax error:

```
<script>
function displayResult(){

  var myObject=document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var myValue = $('#myContent').text();

  for(var i=0; i<myObject.length; i++){                        
    ...
  }
  // missing closing } for function body
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing bracket to `displayResult`.